# Combining Flowable and Single with groupBy

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have two different documents with a relation:

```
class Foo {
    String getBarId();
    String message();
}
class Bar {
    String id();
    String description();
}
```

Given a `Flowable` of `Foo`, I have to merge it with a `Single` of `Bar` and and append the String message. This is the non reactive code:

```
public void sendMessageToBar() {
    getFoo()
          .collect(groupingBy(Foo::getBarId))
          .entrySet()
          .stream()
          .collect(toMap(
                 entry -> getBar(entry.getKey)),
                 entry -> entry.getValue().stream().collect(joining(""))))
          .entrySet()
          .forEach((b,s) -> sendMessage(b,s));
}

public void sendMessage(Bar bar, String message) {}
```

How can I move it to reactive?

So I have the following functions:

- `Flowable<Foo> getFoo();`
- `Single<Bar> getBar(String barId);`
- `Completable sendMessage(Bar bar, String message);`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The grouping process is nearly identical. The feature to note is that the grouped observable has a method, `getKey()` that tells you which `Bar` id you need to use. Then collect the `Foo` items that refer to that `Bar` with the `toList()` operator, convert it to a string and pass it to `sendMessage()`. The `Pair<?,?>` class just pairs up values, and can be hand-rolled in a couple of minutes.

```
getFoo()
  .groupBy(Foo::getBarId)
  .flatMap( groupedObservable ->
     getBar( groupedObservable.getKey() )
       .toObservable()
       .zipWith( groupedObservable
                   .toList()
                   .toObservable(), (b, listOfFoo) -> new Pair<String, String>( b, listOfFoo..stream().collect(joining(""))) )
       .subscribe( result ->
          sendMessage(result.getFirst(), result.getSecond()) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am having a compiling error: 
`Cannot resolve method zipWith(Single<List<Foo>>,'<lamba>')`.

Comment: I edited my answer to include `toObservable()`. I apologise for that: I find `Single` very uncomfortable to work with because it does not play well with others.

Answer (score 0):

Just `flatMap` the foos onto the bars and bars onto `sendMessage`s:

```java
Flowable<Foo> foos = ...

foos.flatMapCompletable(foo ->
   getBar(foo.getBarId())
   .flatMapCompletable(bar -> 
        sendMessage(bar, foo.message())
   )
, 1) // <-- how many concurrent getBars and thus sendMessages to allow
.subscribe(
    bars -> { /** can be ignored ?! */ }, 
    error -> { /* handle errors */ }
)
```

Comment: That's not what I am asking, please read it better. Anyway this code doesn't work, you have to `repeat` the emission of the `Single`.

Comment: Well, next time please  read the [JavaDocs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#flatMapSingle-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) better of the available operators.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved:

```
return getFoo()
  .groupBy(Foo::getBarId)
  .flatMapSingle(group - > {
    final Single < String > message = group.toList().map(f - > f.stream()
      .map(Foo::getMessage).collect(joining("")));
    return getBar(group.getKey()).zipWith(message, Maps::
      immutableEntry);
  })
  .flatMapCompletable(s - > sendMessage(s.getKey(), s.getValue()));
```